# Determining image sizes for multiple android screen sizes/densities

Tags: android, interface, resolution

I've been reviewing the [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://d.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) documentation on the Android and I just need some additional clarification...

It's my understanding that designing three unique interfaces (ldpi, mdpi, and hdpi) would be the best way to go about supporting all the potential android screens with minimal scaling/distortion.

Yes, I know there are similar questions posted, however... If I create an image for the benchmark mdpi (let's say my image is 300x210, just for example) how to I determine what size I will need to recreate that image at ldpi & hdpi? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922697/not-understanding-how-to-use-different-density-images-for-1-6) as well as a google search leads me to believe that ldpi is just 75% of the mdpi image, and the hdpi is 150% of the mdpi image. Is this accurate?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`-ldpi` is ~120dpi, `-mdpi` is ~160dpi, `-hdpi` is ~240dpi.

So, a 320px wide image is 2" in `-mdpi`. If you want a 2" image on `-ldpi`, you want it to be 240px (=75% of original). If you want a 2" picture on `-hdpi`, you need 480px (=150% of original).

Hence, your analysis is accurate.

Comment: @deviant: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html -- "xhdpi: Extra high-density screens; approximately 320dpi". `-xxhdpi` is officially undocumented, so I am not certain what its conversion is. My guess would be 400dpi, but that is just a guess.

Comment: Update to CommonsWare comment: xxhdpi is 480dpi (3x baseline)

Comment: I have a image of 50*43 size i want to get the ldpi, hdpi, mdpi and xhdpi. How can I do dat?