# Error inflating class fragment for SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a SupportMapFragment being used and in every device i've tested it on it has worked fine. I got an error report for a java.io.FileNotFoundException with the following:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.koosprozinski.westernwheels/com.koosprozinski.westernwheels.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2073)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2098)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1204)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:408)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2050)
at com.koosprozinski.westernwheels.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5202)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2037)
... 11 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/maps_btn_myl.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020115
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1957)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:673)
at maps.ai.a.c(Unknown Source)
at maps.af.al.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.af.be.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.af.bd.a(Unknown Source)
at cmi.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:884)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1066)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1168)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:280)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
... 21 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi-v14/maps_btn_myl_pressed.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f020117
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1974)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:673)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:881)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:818)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1954)
... 40 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-hdpi-v14/maps_btn_myl_pressed.png
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:407)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1966)
... 45 more
```

Here is my main activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What exactly could be causing this? As far as I am aware, the vast majority of users are not experiencing this and I can't think of any way to try and replicate it.

Comment: look at my answer, and change your mainactivity.xml. if the answer is useful, accept the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And here is the solution! [NullPointerException from Google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188394/nullpointerexception-from-google-maps)
Insert the SD card if you don't have an internal one! Google din't fix that problem since 2013.

Comment: I never expected to see an answer to this and never would have imagined it would be something like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Try the following, it worked for me:

```
<application>    
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="API KEY" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Comment: Tried that too. Doesn't help with inflation on API 10 device.

Comment: @halxinate, have you found a solution for API 10 device?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to make like this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Not android:name. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I changed it to that now. It works fine for me, but then again it did before too. Any reason something like that would only happen on some devices?

Comment: I don't really know but I think it's a support problem. Your ResourcesNotFound is with **drawable-hdpi-v14**. Maybe you should read this to more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7832560/2668136

Comment: Have the exact same issue. Tried this "solution" too. It does not help on older devices (API 10). Somewhere else I saw that Compatibility lib doesn't like a nested Fragment (like we both have - within a Layout, but mine is inside a FrameLayout). And that a later addition to the project. Before that it worked just perfectly fine on both 23 and 10 APIs.

Answer (score 1):

On your main activity xml, change `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`

to this :

`class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`