# NullPointerException from Google maps

Tags: android, maps

I've just recently started to receive a nullpointerexception from Android google maps and I can't figure out what causes it. Currently it has only been reported on a HTC Desire 500 (z4u) device running android 4.1. Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

So I've gotten my hands on a device that gives the error (HTC Desire, Android 4.1.2, HTC SDK API 5.26). As I suspected from trace it is purely internal error. 
Following didn't help:

- Rebooting
- reinstall
- Newest version of google play services
- Update app to use play services 8.3.0

The stack trace is seen bellow:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {dk.mobikom.android/dk.mobikom.android.activities.ContactDetailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3036)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3077)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2373)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.ad.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.h.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.y.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.bd.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ev.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.z.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.y.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1026)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2012)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1189)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:2011)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:187)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:426)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:415)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:141)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5161)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3019)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Looks like Google Maps issue with latest version of Google maps (I haven't seen this issue on v7.8). We are using Google Maps v8.3 , what version are you using?

Comment: any solution how to resolve this kind of problem sir?

Comment: @Ram No not yet. Investigating if client update of google play services could solve problem...

Comment: Im also getting this on HTC Desire X 4.1.1

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9021&q=NullPointerException&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal

Comment: @Yuraj Thanks, I'll encourage everyone to go and star the issue.

Comment: Same issue with Htc Desire VC 4.0.4, developers are still counting on Google to role out a fix.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So as suspected this is an issue at googles side. They've verified the bug and are working on a fix (2015-12-21), see [googles bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9021&q=NullPointerException&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal) for up to date info about the issue.

**Edit:**

So I got to test Georges SD info and yes inserting a SD card solved the problem. So from this we can conclude phones that don't have an internal fake-external storage (like most phones now a days) will crash from this bug... So this might be a workaround for those who work in the enterprise segment but for those working in the consumer segment this will not really help a lot...

**Edit Jan 20, 2016**

A developer from the Google team has announced the fix has been made and it will be rolled out with the next major release of Google play, but they haven't set a timeline for that yet.

**Edit Jun 02, 2016**

A developer from the Google team has announced it is confirmed fixed:

> Sorry this took so long to fix, but here is the bug fix you've been
>   waiting for!
>
> We can confirm that this issue is now fixed in version 9.0.83 of
>   Google Play Services, released in May 2016.

Comment: same problem here ! please notice everybody when this be fixed

Comment: @JoeCoolman the easiest thing is to go star the issue at Google then you'll get an update automatically. I'll update this post but I don't think you'll get a notification from that.

Comment: Ok @Warpzit, I see this problem appeared in December 12 and until today it has not been fixed by Google programmers, wow :O

Comment: In my case I got also android.view.InflateException and after that, somewhere really deep, I got yours NullPointer. Got it 3 hours solving and trying every dump solution guys from other 10 threads on stackoverflow suggested. Thank you so much.

Comment: Don't know why its taking so long! Its simple fix, just fallback to internal storage in case of no sdcard!

Comment: Removing <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> from Google Play Services 8.3 helped me to avoid this crash (tested under 4.0.3)

Answer (score 5):

Ok found the solution in my case 5 hours later.

Without touching the device (HTC Desire X 4.1.1) all I did is install an SD card and the error magically disappeared. Install SD card, reboot (updated Google photos in the process by I don't think it has anything to do with the issue).

For crying out loud !

Comment: I'll get to test this during the weekend ;) looking forward to see if that is the  case.

Comment: Thanks for info George. This will actually help me as I work with customers in the enterprise segment.

Answer (score 1):

Adding size of SD card on my Emulator worked for me.

[Emulator Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE9A2.png)

Answer (score -2):

Have u tried these

```
<!-- EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions are optional for Android 6.0 onwards. -->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
```

This may solve the issue.

Comment: Since the issue happens internally with Google maps the suggestion is pretty silly. Also Google acknowledge that there is a bug. And third yes the app has these permissions already.