# Crash in Marshmallow Fragment Activity for Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragmentactivity

I am using fragmentActivity for maps.In Java class getting error on  setContentView. My Mapscreen.java is like: It is working fine on some devices showing crash on marshmallow only.Or is there any other reason?

```
public class MapScreen extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener,
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_screen);
    ....

    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    googleMap = fm.getMap();
}

    and my xml has fragment using SupportMapFragment as well. map_screen.xml is like :


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/startActivityButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
           android:background="@drawable/end_meetup_btn"
         />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I am not able to find the same question **Getting crash here in Marshmallow: "Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment" Please suggest!**
Tried to find "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.mkdir()' on a null object reference" also.

```
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026): Process: com.kindlebit.urban_exchange, PID: 8026
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kindlebit.urban_exchange/com.kindlebit.urban_exchange.MapScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at com.kindlebit.urban_exchange.MapScreen.onCreate(MapScreen.java:109)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     ... 9 more
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     ... 17 more
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.mkdir()' on a null object reference
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.ad.a(Unknown Source)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.h.a(Unknown Source)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.y.a(Unknown Source)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.bd.a(Unknown Source)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ev.a(Unknown Source)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.z.a(Unknown Source)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.y.a(Unknown Source)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:995)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1185)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1287)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2243)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:278)
    12-18 13:40:14.425: E/AndroidRuntime(8026):     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
```

Comment: What you have specified in your manifest??

Comment: <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="key" />

Comment: <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Issue was on "Micro-max Android one mobile" which was 6.0 Marshmallow. 
this device has not enough internal or external memory space.Even does not have SD card.

After following answer of **George** from this :

[NullPointerException from Google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188394/nullpointerexception-from-google-maps)

i installed memory card and now crash is not coming.

So i found problem was Updated Google Play services which require Space (updated Google photos ) that was not enough in my device.

and also one of the Error line was showing "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.mkdir()' on a null object reference"

i decided to check after installing SD-card. And it worked

Comment: What a mistake it was !

Comment: yes you are right. I have faces same issue on micromax AQ4509

Comment: I want to catch this error and show a message to end user to insert SD Card.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions are optional for Android 6.0 onwards. -->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
```

Add this to your manifest. Maybe maps need sdcard permission for some extra caching or something.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been fixed in version 9.0.83 of Google Play Services library.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a workaround I did. If the below check fails, instead of loading the map, I load a fragment with an error.

```
/** Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add SD card permissions to your manifest file.

```
    <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
     />

    <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    />
```