# Getting android.view.InflateException while loading map in Marshmallow Devices

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to load map in my fragment Activity and getting the XML inflating error. The crash is only getting in Marshmallow (using Micromax AQ4501 - Android 6.0).

While googling i found same scenario [Check out here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351392/crash-in-marshmallow-fragment-activity-for-maps)

I tried the same and issue is solved by inserting SD card. But i need a right method to solve this. It may be very rare case and i cannot go for a SD availability check in all devices.Guide me to solve this issue.

Happy Coding !

Comment: I guess [this](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9021&q=NullPointerException&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal) will give you a clearer view of the problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue was on "Micro-max Android one mobile" which was 6.0 Marshmallow. this device has not enough internal or external memory space.Even does not have SD card.

I gone through many sites and found problem was Updated Google Play services which require Space (updated Google photos ) that was not enough in my device and also one of the Error line was showing

```
 "Caused by:   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.mkdir()' on a null object reference"
```

I decided to check after installing SD-card. And it worked

Comment: yes Joyal you are right.I was gone through same issue and after installing memory card the issue was gone.Thanks man..