# Android Google Maps crashes after upgrade to 8.4

Tags: java, android, google-maps, crash, stack-trace

after upgrading my play-services to 8.4 I noticed google maps crashed immediately after app launch. I didn't change any code since I upgraded to 8.4, so my assumption is that this issue is a google maps related bug.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                        at com.google.a.a.ae.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.k.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.k.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.y.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.bd.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ev.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.z.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.y.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
                                                                        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2042)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1976)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1092)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

There also seems to be no issue in my code, otherwise it would be noted in the stacktrace here, so probably a google bug, just wanted to ask if anyone has the same issue before reporting it as a bug.

Comment: This stack trace looks very similar to following issue;  https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9011 , are you using vector drawables too?

Comment: No I am not, I am however setting a custom hue color to the markers by using `BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(hue)`, but the app crashes before the markers are loaded so that should not be the problem

Comment: I found this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188394/nullpointerexception-from-google-maps?noredirect=1#comment56449930_34188394) that might help clear things up. Have you tried inserting the SD Card?

Comment: I set the emulator to use a studio managed sd card, after increasing the sd card size it worked fine, so it also seems to be an issue with not enough sd card space