# NPE in google maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm getting some crash reports when inflating maps fragment in some of the kitkat devices.

```
Caused  by:  java.lang.NullPointerException
        at  com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.ad.a(Unknown  Source)
        at  com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.h.a(Unknown  Source)
        at  com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.y.a(Unknown  Source)
        at  com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.bd.a(Unknown  Source)
        at  com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ev.a(Unknown  Source)
        at  com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.z.a(Unknown  Source)
        at  com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.y.a(Unknown  Source)
        at  com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
        at  android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
        at  com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown  Source)
        at  com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown  Source)
        at  com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown  Source)
        at  com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown  Source)
        at  com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown  Source)
        at  com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown  Source)
        at  android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1965)
        at  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1047)
        at  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1237)
        at  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1339)
        at  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2295)
        at  android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
        at  android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
        at  android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
        at  android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
        at  android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
        ...  22  more
```

There is an issue filled [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5100). Any one faced this issue, and this is not the same issue with sdcard.

Comment: Please share the xml code as well.

Comment: also share the `Activity` code...

Comment: Your confident it's not the "SD card issue" [discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188394/nullpointerexception-from-google-maps)?

Comment: @qbix yeah, if it is SD card issue, it should be different trace, with File.mkdir(). And the customer mobile has SD card installed. And we cannot reproduce this issue, and occurs only in 4.x according to [issues with comment #23](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9021&q=NullPointerException&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal)