# mClustermanager.additem() google maps throwing null pointer exception android

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    MyItem myItem;
    private ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;






        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(31.530136,74.353225), 10));

        // Initialize the manager with the context and the map.
        // (Activity extends context, so we can pass 'this' in the constructor.)
        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, mMap);

        // Point the map's listeners at the listeners implemented by the cluster
        // manager.
        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

        // Add cluster items (markers) to the cluster manager.
       // addItems();
        myItem = new MyItem(31.530136,74.353225);
mClusterManager.addItem(myItem);
        myItem = new MyItem(31.529807, 74.352495);
        mClusterManager.addItem(myItem);
        myItem = new MyItem(31.530584, 74.353729);
        mClusterManager.addItem(myItem);
        myItem = new MyItem(31.531319, 74.351217);
        mClusterManager.addItem(myItem);






        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
//        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
//        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
//        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
    private void addItems() {

        // Set some lat/lng coordinates to start with.
        double lat = 31.531034;
        double lng = 74.352374;


        // Add ten cluster items in close proximity, for purposes of this example.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            double offset = i / 60d;
            lat = lat + offset;
            lng = lng + offset;
            MyItem offsetItem = new MyItem(lat, lng);
            mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
        }
    }


}
```

Above class represents the code to add marker coordinates in cluster utility library offered by Google maps in android. But when I run the code it gives the error at mClustermanager.addItem() gives null pointer exception.

Comment: it seems your `mMap` is null

Comment: if i simply apply markers using mMap it actually works but with clustermanager it throw null pointer exception

Comment: did you implements ClusterItem for MyItem class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I actually found a couple of issues ([Issue 7696](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7696) and [Issue 9021](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9021&q=NullPointerException&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal)) logged in gmaps-api-issues.

But, I'm quite not sure if your case is somehow related to those existing issues.

However, you may try the given workaround:

> User's upgrading Google Play Services on their device to 9.0.83 will fix this issue. You do not need to update the SDK version.

For added more detail information, this SO post - [NullPointerException from Google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188394/nullpointerexception-from-google-maps) might also help.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem by copying the MyItem class from the demo app at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/setup (the zip file under "Get the Maps SDK for Android utility library")