# android: Unable to start activity

Tags: android

I am getting the following error on this line  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_trip);`

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: online.hannuveda.transafe_tx, PID: 2067
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{online.hannuveda.transafe_tx/online.hannuveda.transafe_tx.trip}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #197: Error inflating class fragment
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:183)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5651)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #197: Error inflating class fragment
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                      at online.hannuveda.transafe_tx.trip.onCreate(trip.java:219)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6119)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2491)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:183) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5651) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                      at maps.G.a.a(Unknown Source)
                      at maps.V.N.a(Unknown Source)
                      at maps.D.e.a(Unknown Source)
                      at maps.D.p.a(Unknown Source)
                      at maps.ad.ae.a(Unknown Source)
                      at maps.ad.t.a(Unknown Source)
                      at maps.ad.M.a(Unknown Source)
                      at ul.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:107)
                      at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:385)
                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1065)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1268)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1370)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2415)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:376)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                      at online.hannuveda.transafe_tx.trip.onCreate(trip.java:219) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6119) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2491) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:183) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5651) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Here is the corresponding XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="online.hannuveda.transafe_tx.trip">
    <Button
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Show details"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#ffa500"
        android:onClick="DetailExpander"
        android:id="@+id/Button_Expander" />
    <com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:ael_duration="500"
        app:ael_expanded="false"
        app:ael_orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/Expander"
        app:ael_interpolator="bounce">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="monospace"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Trip ID"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textColor="#27bd0d"/>
                <TextView
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:text="Hello"
                    android:typeface="monospace"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#ffa500"
                    android:id="@+id/TextView_TripID" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="monospace"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Driver"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textColor="#27bd0d"/>
                <TextView
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:text="Hello"
                    android:typeface="monospace"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#ffa500"
                    android:id="@+id/TextView_Driver" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="monospace"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Bus no"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textColor="#27bd0d"/>
                <TextView
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:text="Hello"
                    android:typeface="monospace"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#ffa500"
                    android:id="@+id/TextView_BusNo" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="monospace"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Trip Start Time"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textColor="#27bd0d"/>
                <TextView
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:text="Hello"
                    android:typeface="monospace"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#ffa500"
                    android:id="@+id/TextView_TripStartTime" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="monospace"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Sent Data"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textColor="#27bd0d"/>
                <TextView
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:typeface="monospace"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#ffa500"
                    android:id="@+id/TextView_SentData" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="monospace"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Buffered Data"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textColor="#27bd0d"/>
                <TextView
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:typeface="monospace"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#ffa500"
                    android:id="@+id/TextView_BufferedData"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/googleMap"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:typeface="monospace"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="End"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#ffa500"
            android:onClick="EndTrip"
            android:id="@+id/Button_EndTrip" />
        <Button
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:typeface="monospace"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#ffa500"
            android:onClick="CancelTrip"
            android:id="@+id/Button_CancelTrip" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am unsure why is it giving error related to Array. Can anyone please help me out here.

Comment: I also faced this error before in Android Studio and solved it by Uninstalling app Rebuild from android studio and again run the app on device

Comment: Have you tried to identify the location of the error? Tried removing parts of your layout?

Comment: You don't really need `android:layout_weight="1"` within your `<fragment.../>`

Comment: @RvdK check my question I have mentioned exactly on which line the error is occurring.

Comment: @AkshayJ So the error points to your googleMap fragment, if you remove it, it works? If so, please update your question with that part. Readers should not need to manually lookup the correct line by counting the lines or using a text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is solved here:

[NullPointerException from Google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188394/nullpointerexception-from-google-maps)

Insert the SD card if you don't have an internal one! Google din't fix that problem since 2013.

Comment: Switched off the phone, reinserted the SD card, Switched it On, and it worked !